# ¿Cómo hacer un CRUD REALTIME con vuex y socketio?

Tags: nodejs, vue.js, express, socket.io, vuex

Quiero realizar un `CRUD` realtime utilizando `Vuex`, `Node`, `Express` y `Socket.io` pero utilizando la siguiente sintaxis no logro obtener el resultado.

**Servidor:**

- index.js

```
    const server = app.listen('3000',() => {
        console.log('<--- Web Server Starter --->')
        const io = require('./sockets')(server)
        io.on('connection', socket=>{
            console.log('client connected');
        })
    })
```

- socket.js

```
            let io
            module.exports = {
                init:httpServer =>{
                    io = require('socket.io')(httpServer)
                    return io
                },
                getIo:()=>{ 
                    if(!io){
                        throw new Error('socket io not initialized')
                    }
                    return io
                }
            }
```

- user.js

```
    const io = require('../socket')
    router.post('/newuser',(req, res) => {
        res.json({ serverResponse: 'userCreated' })
        io.getIo().emit('newuser',{serverResponse:'created',user:user})
    })
```

**Cliente:**

- Modulo user.js (VUEX actions)

```
    getusers({ commit }){
        const sessionToken = localStorage.getItem('sessionToken')
        axios.get('/newuser', {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('sessionToken')}`
            },
        })
            .then(response => {
                const socket = openSocket('http://localhost:3000')
                socket.on('newuser', data => {
                    if (data.serverResponse === 'created') {
                        this.users = data.user
                        commit('GET_USERS', users)
                    })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert(error)
            })
    })
```

Cuando creo el nuevo usuario, en el cliente no se actualiza la lista de usuarios automáticamente, sino que tengo que refrescar la página, ¿por qué pasa esto?

Comment: ¿Porqué crees que usar `axios.get()` en el cliente será capturado por `router.post()` en el servidor? Recuerda que en HTTP los verbos GET y POST son totalmente diferentes. En todo caso deberías usar `axios.post()` en el cliente, si tu servidor está esperando una solicitud de ese tipo. Cambia eso y comenta el resultado. Saludos

Comment: los get y post no pintan nada en el objetivo, ya que si quieres usar socket no necesitas axios. solo socket cliente y socket server

Answer (score 2):

> - axios es para hacer peticiones HTTP
> - sockets abren un canal de comunicación entre cliente servidor
>
> O usas axios, o usas sockets.

Lo voy a hacer como si fuese un solo archivo, ya tu lo distribuyes como quieras. Esto porque no vi en ninguna parte tu `index.js` donde llames a `user.js`

#### Cliente

```
const socket = openSocket('http://localhost:3000') // esto lo tomé de tu codigo no estoy seguro si funciona

socket.emit('newuser', form ); // te conectas al canal y envías los datos del formulario

// Medio por el que escucha si el servidor responde a la conexion con newuser
socket.on('usercreated', msg => {
    console.log( msg )
});
```

### Server

```
const io = require('./sockets')(server)
io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('client connected');

  socket.on('newuser', function( form ){
    
    // Tu codigo sea lo que sea que haga

    io.emit('usercreated', 'Usuario creado con exito' );
  });

})

const server = app.listen('3000',() => {
    console.log('<--- Web Server Starter --->')
})
```

> En teoría así es como debe funcionar... acomodalo a tu gusto.. [LEE LA DOCUMENTACION](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/)